# JpaRepository Retrieving Child from Parent

Tags: java, jpa, repository, relationship

How to Retrieving Child from Parent ?.

Let say i have parent class and child class. And i want to retrieve list of child from parent side.

This is my Parent Class.

```
+import ...
@Entity

public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Child> Childs = new ArrayList<>();

    private String name;

    * Getter and Setter are hide
}
```

This is my Parent Child.

```
+import ...

@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne()
    private Parent parent;

    private String childNote;

    * Getter and Setter are hide
}
```

This is my Repository

```
@Repository
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT p.childs FROM Parent p where p.id =:id")     
    List<Child> findxx(Long id);
}
```

That give me an error :

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-03-05 00:59:16.281 ERROR 444 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'parentRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'parentRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.test.ParentRepository.findxx(java.lang.Long)!
... I cut-off this line's 

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'parentRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.test.ParentRepository.findxx(java.lang.Long)!
... I cut-off this line's 

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.test.ParentRepository.findxx(java.lang.Long)!
... I cut-off this line's 

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: childs of: com.example.test.Parent [SELECT p.childs FROM com.example.test.Parent p where p.id =:id]
... I cut-off this line's 

Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: childs of: com.example.test.Parent [SELECT p.childs FROM com.example.test.Parent p where p.id =:id]
... I cut-off this line's 

Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: childs of: com.example.test.Parent
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-
... I cut-off this line's
```

Really need your advice.

Jigu

Comment: You cannot select a MULTI-VALUED field in JPQL. As you should read in any JPQL docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c FROM Child c where c.parent.id =:id
```

Comment: How if, I want to add example and pageable as parameter ?

Comment: @Query(value = "SELECT c FROM Child c where c.parent.id =:id")

Comment: public List<Child> findChildById(String id, Example example, Pageable pageable);

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'parentRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.relationship.ParentRepository.findChildById(java.lang.String,org.hibernate.criterion.Example,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable) but parameter 'Optional[example]' not found in annotated query 'SELECT c FROM Child c where c.parent.id =:id'!